# Using UPDATE to insert a value returned by a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where I want to update a column with the value in another column in the previous row.

I want to do something like this.

```
UPDATE myTable as b SET prev=(SELECT top 1 myField FROM myTable 
WHERE rowID<b.rowID ORDER By rowID Desc)
```

Any ideas?

Note: I'm using Access/SQL server.  I am getting an error 'operation must use an updatable query'.

Note2: The solution from [How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server) doesnt work.

Comment: Are you getting  an error when running the above?

Comment: Please indicate the DBMS--SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.

Comment: Looks like Microsoft SQL Server, what else uses `TOP`?

Comment: This will have the answer you're looking for: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server

Comment: I am getting an error 'operation must use an updatable query'

Comment: DLeh, the stackflow suggestion you quoted doesn't workUPDATE
    mytable SET
    prev =myfield
FROM
    mytable 
INNER JOIN
    mytable as a
ON
    mytable.Timeid =a.Timeid-2

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a combination of the LAG() analytic function to compute the value of  for the previous row and an UPDATE (here, I'm using a MERGE statement):

```
MERGE INTO mytable as target using (
  select 
    t.id,
    lag(field1) over (partition by null order by id) new_prev_field
  from mytable t
) as src (id, new_prev_field)
on (target.id = src.id)
when matched 
then update
  set prev_field1 = src.new_prev_field;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ad78/14)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of Top, use Max()

```
UPDATE myTable as b 
SET prev = (
  SELECT max(rowID)
  FROM myTable 
  WHERE rowID < b.rowID)
```

Comment: That doesn't do what the OP wants - he wants some field_value from the previous row, not the rowID of the previous row.

Comment: True, I interpreted it incorrectly. In my defense best practice would be to store the ID, as then you could join back to the table and get whatever dimension/attribute needed rather than physically store one.